# get text from table cell in different format

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like write a function `get_text` to get text from table td tags. But text can be wrapped/styled different ways in the tds. So far I have following code. I cannot figure out how I can have both text in list in case 1 and case 2

```
def get_text(xpath):
    e = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('{}//*[not(./*)]'.format(xpath))
    if not e:
        e = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        return [e.text]

    return [o.text for o in e]

case 1
<td class = "" >
    <span >
        <span >
            <span > prefix text 1 < /span >
        < / span >
        text 1
    < / span >
< / td >
# return ['prefix text 1', 'text 1']

case 2:
<td class = "" >
    <div >
        <span > prefix text 2 < /span >
    < / div >
    text 2
< / td >
# return ['prefix text 2', 'text 2']

case 3:
<td class = "" >
    test3
< / td >
# return ['test3']

case 4:
<div >
    <a href = "#" >
        link text 4
    < / a >
    <div >
        <span >
            <span > prefix text 4 < /span >
        < / span >
        <span >
            text 4
        < / span >
    < / div >
< / div >
# return ['link text 4', 'prefix text 4', 'text 4']
```

Comment: try change the xpath into `//td[@class="" and //span]`

Comment: Do they have to be returned separately? You could just loop through the TDs and pull the text and you'd get both.

Comment: i just would like to write a generic function that can get text under td tag in those condition.basically, xpath is always in the format tr[{}]/td[{}].format(row, col) as input